# Why it is asking for 4 input instead of 3?

Tags: c

Why it is asking for 4 input instead of  3 ? 
I have used only 3 scanf in my program.
This is a program about finding smallest and largest number among 3 variables.
Please Help...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
    int first, second, third;
    printf("Enter 3 integers for compare:");
    scanf("%d\n",&first);
    scanf("%d\n",&second);
    scanf("%d\n",&third);
    if((first>second) && (first>third))
        printf("First number is the largest\n");
    else if((second>first) && (second>third))
        printf("Second number is the largest\n");
    else if((third>second) && (third>first))
        printf("\nThird number is the largest\n");

    if((first<second) && (first<third))
        printf("First number is smallest\n");
    else if((second<first) && (second<third))
        printf("Second number is smallest\n");
    else if((third<second) && (third<first))
        printf("Third number is smallest\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/QYjmYi

Comment: @user3121023 that's the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take your last call to `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d\n",&third);
```

The `"\n"` at the end of the format string means the `scanf` function will read and discard any white-space after the input, but it can't know when the white-space ends until there is something which is *not* a white-space character. That means you need to enter some extra input for `scanf` to be satisfied.

So the simple solution is to just don't have the newlines in your `scanf` format strings.